# Series of automatic logouts

Tags: bug, status-declined, google-chrome

Using Chrome 18; I've been getting logged out automatically and for no apparent reason. Is this deliberate? Can you fix?

Answer (score 2):

We do not support beta browsers. We only support released browsers.

Comment: This is not the first time it has happened. It only became more common today. This has happened to me on chrome 16.